# What can cause PowerShell to not support "-As Datatables" in a Invoke-Sqlcmd query

Tags: powershell, sql-server

I'm trying to track down a failure on a CI server.  It's running a PowerShell command:

`$dt = Invoke-Sqlcmd -server $dbServer -database $dbName $sqlQueryReport -As DataTables -QueryTimeout 900`

This errors out with "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'As'".  But according to [the documentation,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) "-As DataTables" is a perfectly legitimate parameter to pass to Invoke-Sqlcmd.

I do notice that, in the documentation, it puts the `-Query` parameter tag before the SQL query, and this CI script doesn't.  But it's not giving similar errors on other scripts in this CI job that omit `-Query`, so it's not clear whether that's relevant or not.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Maybe an older version of the cmdlet.  If you use `-OutputAs Datatables` instead does it work?

Comment: @squillman When I do that it says ""A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'OutputAs'""

Comment: Ok, then it may be that you need to also includ the `-query` param (but not positive, I can't find the docs that describe `-As` and `-OutputAs` at the moment...)

Comment: @squillman I did that too.  Doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an older Version of the [`SqlServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) Module where this Parameter was not implemented yet, or even use the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` Version from the [`SQLPS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) module, where this Parameter isn't implemented at all.

Check the Version and Source module of the command like this:

```
PS C:\Users\Simon> get-command invoke-sqlcmd

CommandType     Name                                     Version    Source
-----------     ----                                     -------    ------
Cmdlet          Invoke-Sqlcmd                            21.1.18256 SqlServer
```

If the source is not SqlServer, or the Version is not 21.1.18256 install/update the module:

Update:

```
Update-Module SqlServer
```

Install:

```
Find-Module SqlServer | Install-Module
```